# How to convert 'Integer' to 'Timestamps'?

Tags: discord.net

**I did a effort but got error while testing

> Error BC30311 Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'Timestamps'.**

I have tried this :

```
 Public Sub test()

    client = New DiscordRpcClient("test")

    client.Logger = New ConsoleLogger

    client.Initialize()



    client.SetPresence(New RichPresence With {
        .Details = "test",
        .Assets = New Assets() With {
        .LargeImageKey = "test",
        .LargeImageText = "test",
        .Timestamps = 0
    })

    Dim timer = New System.Timers.Timer(150)
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, Sub(sender, args)
                                  client.Invoke()
                              End Sub

    timer.Start()

    client.Invoke()
    End Sub
```

here the problem is "Timestamps = 0", So how can i solve. 
im trying to use discord rich Presence elapsed timer.

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Comment: because i already have knowledge with C#, so i though i can get help from C# developers

Comment: What is the definition of RichPresence.Timestamps ?

Comment: rich presence discord. (googled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually more of an issue with this Discord-RPC-Csharp library than it is with C#. That being said, I looked into it anyway.

The example code given in the repository for this project shows this as an example

```
Timestamps = Timestamps.FromTimeSpan(10)
```

See the error you got is an error specific to C# for when trying to assign one value type to a complete different type. An Integer is not a Timestamp, and a Timestamp is not an Integer. So we need to figure out what Timestamps actually is. So the best way to do this is to right-click on Timestamps and go to "Go To Definition" or hit F12 on it.

Now in RichPresence.cs you can see the class definition for Timestamps. You will see four options

```
Timestamps.Now
Timestamps.FromTimeSpan(double seconds)
Timestamps.FromTimeSpan(Timespan timespan)
```

in addition to a constructor

```
new Timestamps(DateTime start, DateTime end)
```

Since you haven't told us what this timestamp is supposed to represent in your code, I'll leave it to you to figure out which one of these you want/need to use.

Comment: Worked, yeh i figure out, Thanks

Comment: but it reduce time not adding. (time left), not elapsed.